# BootCamp can't partition

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

I had a problem with my Macbook that couldn't read the internal SSD and boot OS X, but I solve it: [MacBook does not mount, does not boot, does not read drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220018/macbook-does-not-mount-does-not-boot-does-not-read-drive/220034?noredirect=1#comment267746_220034) .

I used resizeStack method to get the full size of the disk on OS X. The problem I have now is when I press ALT key on startup it shows two bootable disks. *Macintosh HD* and *Windows*. *Windows* was a partitioned disk I had for windows and is empty (maybe).

After using resizeStack it shouldn't be there. When I open Boot Camp Assistant to reinstall Windows, I get the message that there is an "error partitioning the disk".

[image: Results of: sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0 and sudo fdisk /dev/disk0]

Comment: Will Disk Utility recognize the partition? If so, try removing the partition then adding it again.

Comment: No, i forget to mention that.

Comment: Before having the problems i mention on the old question, i used VMWare for virtual machine. I don't know if it made something automatically.

Comment: @klanomath message from boot camp: `**Your disk could not be partitioned** An error occurred while partitioning the disk`

Comment: @klanomath I did a restart and now Windows doesn't show on startup! Only Macintosh HD .. But what about BootCamp now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following:

1. Boot to Recovery HD by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while starting your Mac, open Disk Utility and first check the superior disk, then inferior volume for errors and repair them if necessary.
2. Boot to single user mode by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> while starting your Mac and enter `fsck -fy`. If you get a message stating ""FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED", reenter `fsck -fy` until you get the message "The volume … appears to be OK". Then enter `reboot`.
3. If you still can't reinstall Windows with Boot Camp Assistant consider rebuilding the GUID partition table.

Comment: @AlexAndreadis You are welcome ;-) Have fun installing Windows and don't create the same mess as last time :-P

Comment: this happened because I tried to have three OS on MacBook. 1. OS X 2. Windows and 3. Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlexAndreadis Are both bootable or only one of them?

Comment: now it's ok.. i don't know what happens. Also Child Count on Disk Utility is  4.